# update columns of dataframe with columns of another dataframe and preserve column order

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','B','c','D'])    
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'B':[3,4]})
```

I'd like to update the empty columns in `df1` with `df2` but keeping the original column order. I tried

```
df1.combine_first(df2)
```

but this changes the order of the columns

```
   B   D  a   c
0  3 NaN  1 NaN
1  4 NaN  2 NaN
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting Pandas Dataframe by order of another index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843911/sorting-pandas-dataframe-by-order-of-another-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `reindex`

```
df2.reindex(df1.columns, axis=1)
Out[44]: 
   a  B   c   D
0  1  3 NaN NaN
1  2  4 NaN NaN
```