# Sorting one dataframe based on column in different dataframe and putting unmatched entries at bottom

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have two dataframes that share an ID column between them.
The first dataframe is split out and sent to the owners of the data for updates.
Once returned, they are put back together into a single dataframe again.
Now one dataframe has been updated and contains new entries with no ID yet and is also in a different order from what is originally was.
df1 is the old, df2 is the new
I want sort df2 based on the ID column in df1 and leave the new entries at the bottom.
The IDs are randomly generated and do not have an order, which is by design.

Is there any good way of doing that?
I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843911/sorting-pandas-dataframe-by-order-of-another-index) post, which makes use of indexing. I could make my ID column the index, but as some new entries would not have an ID yet, that would not work.

I have made a mockup of the situation here:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name','DataOwner','UniqueID'], data=[['P1',1,123],['P2',2,321],['P3',3,456]])
df2=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name','DataOwner','UniqueID'], data=[['P1',1,123],['P4', 1, ],['P2',2,321],['P5',2,],['P3',3,456], ['P6', 3, ]])
```

Which results in these two dataframes:

```
  Name  DataOwner  UniqueID
0   P1          1       123
1   P2          2       321
2   P3          3       456
  Name  DataOwner  UniqueID
0   P1          1     123.0
1   P4          1       NaN
2   P2          2     321.0
3   P5          2       NaN
4   P3          3     456.0
5   P6          3       NaN
```

The names of the projects are descriptive text and cannot be used for sorting, the dataowner is not sorted and just put there to illustrate that the data is returned by dataowner, put together in one big datafram before i need to sort it based on the ID with new entries at the bottom.

The result i want is then to have:

```
  Name  DataOwner  UniqueID
0   P1          1       123
1   P2          2       321
2   P3          3       456
  Name  DataOwner  UniqueID
0   P1          1     123.0
2   P2          2     321.0
4   P3          3     456.0
1   P4          1       NaN
3   P5          2       NaN
5   P6          3       NaN
```

Although the order of the new entries does not matter - they just need to be at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option using a custom key in [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
key = pd.Series({k:v for v,k in enumerate(df['UniqueID'].unique())})

out = df2.sort_values(by='UniqueID', key=key.reindex, na_position='last')
```

Output:

```
  Name  DataOwner  UniqueID
0   P1          1     123.0
2   P2          2     321.0
4   P3          3     456.0
1   P4          1       NaN
3   P5          2       NaN
5   P6          3       NaN
```

Comment: This does work, but not if i use the column UniqueID, which is the only column i can be absolutely certain is going to be unique and be unchanged in between the two datasets. All the other columns are open to changes when being updated.
Thanks even so.

#Edit:
My bad, this works on the UniqueID columns as well - thank you :)

Comment: An important addition i fount later:

If I need to be able to use the same indexing in both dataframes afterwards, I have to reset the index:

`final_sorted_w_reset_index = out.reset_index(drop=True)`

This ensures, that my newly sorted dataframe has the same index at the same rows as the one i used to sort by. Otherwise, if i said:

`df[column][idx]`

And 

`out[column][idx]`, i would be accessing different rows as the index was sorted as well, but not reset

Answer (score 0):

`CategoricalDtype` is my go-to when I need custom sort order. Assume that the index on `df2` is unique:

```py
UniqueIDType = pd.CategoricalDtype(df["UniqueID"], ordered=True)
index = df2["UniqueID"].astype(UniqueIDType).sort_values().index

df2.reindex(index)
```

Comment: This does work thank you very much. Would you be able to explain a little bit what is going on exatcly?